# jakarta.jws.WebService not inject spring beans

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services

My project needs to create a new a new server soap cloning the current server with the same
wsdl, for it I am using

org.codehaus.mojo>jaxws-maven-plugin-2.6

Java 11 + Spring boot 2.7.13 + jakarta.xml.ws-api-4.0.1

Once the The classes have been generated, now I am implementing the service, so:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import jakarta.jws.WebMethod;
import jakarta.jws.WebService;
import lombok.extern.java.Log;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import net.gencat.salut.sivec.external.cases.argo.model.Carrega;
import net.gencat.salut.sivec.external.cases.argo.model.OrdreAltaDadesRegistre;


@WebService(endpointInterface = "net.gencat.salut.sivec.external.cases.argo.model.Carrega")
@Slf4j
public class CarregaImpl implements Carrega {

@Autowired
private OrchestationAlta orchestationAlta;


@Override
@WebMethod(action = "alta")
public OrdreAltaDadesRegistre alta(OrdreAltaDadesRegistre arg0, String arg1, String arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    return orchestationAlta.altaArgo(arg0);

  }
}
```

I have tried of several ways for I don't get it. Using @postContructor , changing @Autowired by injecting the beans of each contructor method and nothing, the orchestationAlta field is always null. ¿What am i doing wrong?

```
@Component
public class OrchestationAltaImpl implements OrchestationAlta{

@Autowired
private PatientService patientService;

@Autowired
private CaseService caseService;



@Override
public OrdreAltaDadesRegistre altaArgo(OrdreAltaDadesRegistre ordreAltaDadesRegistre) {
    try {
        PacientArgoDto pacienteArgoDto = PacientConverter.toPacienteArgoDto(ordreAltaDadesRegistre);            
        PatientResponse patientResponse = patientService.createPatient(pacienteArgoDto);
        
        CaseArgoDto caseArgoDto = CaseConverter.toCaseArgoDto(ordreAltaDadesRegistre);
        CaseRequest caseRequest = CaseConverter.toCaseRequest(caseArgoDto,patientResponse);
        
        caseService.createCase(caseRequest);
        
        ordreAltaDadesRegistre.setCognom1(patientResponse.getFirstName());
        ordreAltaDadesRegistre.setCognom2(patientResponse.getSurname());
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        if(Objects.nonNull(patientResponse.getDateOfbirth())) {
            ordreAltaDadesRegistre.setDataNaixament(patientResponse.getDateOfbirth().format(formatter));
        }
        ordreAltaDadesRegistre.setError("0");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ordreAltaDadesRegistre.setError(null);
        
    }
    return ordreAltaDadesRegistre;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Why should it inject anything, `@WebService` isn't a spring managed bean but rather managed by JAX-WS not Spring.

Comment: Shouldn't you be moving to Spring Boot 3 if using jakarta.xml.ws-api-4.0.1 ([*Jakarta XML Web Services 4*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/xml-web-services/))? I don't know if that relates to your problem or not.

Comment: @M.Deinum,  WebService is an annotation from JAX-WS that is correct, but I need that when I do the call to the Soap Service , the field not be null.  I have check in the Spring context and both classes have been load (CarregaImpl and OrchestationAltaImpl). I have tested adding Inject annotation to OrchestationAltaImpl and nothing. ¿What can i do for fix this issue? I can't use Spring boot WebService because not respect the naming of portType, Binding and elements by default. It's better solution to use CXF ?

Comment: I know what you need, but that isn't going to happen with a non spring managed instance. I do recall there was/is a library that fixes the integration. Regarding Spring-WS you can just configure it to work as you like but that is up to you.